# Пробелы между элементами командной строки

Tags: java

Условие: Вывести в консоль параметры командной строки так, чтобы между ними был пробел, и обязательно, чтобы пробела не было перед первым элементом и после последнего.
Вывожу массивом:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(args[i]);
}
```

Подскажите на счёт пробелов, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [String.join](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-join-examples/):

```java
System.out.print(String.join(" ", args));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей можно использовать [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). Каждую строчку дополнить пробелом спереди, пропустив первый пробел:

```java
String[] args = new String[]{"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"};

Arrays.stream(args)
        .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(" ", line))
        .skip(1)
        .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Вывод:

```
abc def ghi jkl
```

---

См. [How to join list of non-string objects using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451786/11141611)